# Unable to do SFTP after enabling IAP for vms in GCP

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, sftp, google-cloud-platform

I have enabled IAP to ssh the vm , but the problem is after enabling it I am not able to do sftp , previously I was able to sftp using the vpn.

[IAP configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rinpu.jpg)

I can do ssh with gcp console browser or cloud sdk using command

> gcloud compute ssh cicd-testing-vm --tunnel-through-iap
> --zone=us-central1-c

**problem:- I want to do SFTP on GCP vm using 3rd party tools like WinSCP or FileZilla is there any solution for this.**

[trying to sftp through winscp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycGxk.jpg)

[not able to connect "searching for host"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PXKt.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to sftp my vm but IAP is enabled how can I achieve that.